# Error using dcast from Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, dcast

I have a dataset of the form

```
mydat = data.table(id=c(1:10),group=rep(c("trtA","trtB"),5), 
           n=sample(10:50,10,replace=T),y= round(runif(10,0:1),3))

head(mydat)

dcast(mydat,id~group,value.var=c("n","y"),fill=0)
```

works fine working from r-console but the returns error message below in r-studio. I can't quite figure out a solution.

> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds In
>   addition: Warning message: In if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { :
>   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: I tried both in R console (R 3.3.1) and R studio (v  0.99.903) and couldn't reproduce any error with the data you showed

Comment: What are your versions of the various packages involved?